# What function is called on SharePoint Post button click

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, newsfeed

I want to know what function is called when `Sharepoint NewsFeed's` *Post* button is clicked.

I want to override or change it because it adds post image with wrong dimensions

```
<button id="ms-postreplybutton_1.1cb64504733e419c980e01269ed96f7a.049023eae3fc4b27a4755ed99c0e57cf.a28168d7eab4416783ec0599909c7d7f.0c37852b34d0418e91c62ac25af4be5b.6f01a2799a02461a9b636acab1d7fa98.10.10.S-1-5-21-1393957893-2012297305-37170099-80844" type="button" class="ms-microfeed-postButton ms-button-emphasize ms-floatRight" attachid="1.1cb64504733e419c980e01269ed96f7a.049023eae3fc4b27a4755ed99c0e57cf.a28168d7eab4416783ec0599909c7d7f.0c37852b34d0418e91c62ac25af4be5b.6f01a2799a02461a9b636acab1d7fa98.10.10.S-1-5-21-1393957893-2012297305-37170099-80844" disabled="">Post</button>
```

Also can someone explain, what is `attachId` property in button tag

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All the functionalities related to SharePoint Newsfeed is included in `SP.UI.MicroFeed.js` which is a minified version.

You can also find debug version(`SP.UI.MicroFeed.debug.js`) too at

```
C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft shared\Web Server Extensions\15\TEMPLATE\LAYOUTS
```

`$7Z_0` is the function if you want to override

Comment: Thanks
How did you know this function is called ?

Comment: IE Developer Tools